# Android RecyclerView скроллинг до определенного Item

Tags: android, recyclerview

собираюсь писать тестовое задание расписания для вуза.
Имеется 7 возможных пар в день. Я думаю какой компонент выбрать для них.

Думаю можно выбрать RecyclerView для хранения в нем.
У каждой пары есть временной промежуток, когда она длится.

**Вопрос**: есть ли какой нибудь интерфейс для recyclerview, который при загрузки фрагмента может проскроллить до пары, которая идет в нужный момент.

Думаю если нет такой возможности, можно попробовать просто выделить нужную пару цветом

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, если использовать LinearLayoutManager

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

int indexOfItem = getCurrentIndex();
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(indexOfItem , 0);
```

Comment: спасибо, как я понял это нужно делать в onActivityCreated во фрагменте так?

Comment: очевидно нужно так

Answer (score 2):

Класс `RecyclerView` имеет метод [`scrollToPosition(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)), который переместит список в нужную позицию и метод [`smoothScrollToPosition(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)), который сделает это же несколько плавнее.

Например, переместить список к шестому пункту (отсчет позиций начинается с 0)

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(5);
```

Comment: в каком месте я должен использовать этот метод? Сразу как объявили в onViewCreated?

Comment: в том самом месте, где вам нужно переместить список в нужную позицию. Сразу после его выполнения произойдет перемещение. Где же это место именно в вашем коде, известно только вам.